# excludindg a directory from ant copy not working

Tags: java, ant

I have a folder structure like this,

```
 samples/soap-client/target/layout/srcdist/etc/wsdl/v1/...
 samples/soap-client/target/layout/srcdist/etc/wsdl/v2
 samples/soap-client/target/layout/war/.....
```

i want to copy the all content of **layout folder** to another location **except wsdl folder**. my code is like this

```
<copy todir="${pse-layout.dir}/sdk/partnersdk/new-soap-client">
    <fileset dir="samples/soap-client/target/layout">               
        <exclude name="**/**/wsdl/"/>
        <include name="**/*"/>              
    </fileset>
</copy>
```

but this is not working.this copies the whole content of layout folder including wsdl folder. please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your copy task to:

```
<copy todir="${pse-layout.dir}/sdk/partnersdk/new-soap-client">
  <fileset dir="samples/soap-client/target/layout">               
    <include name="**/*"/>              
    <exclude name="**/wsdl/**"/>
  </fileset>
</copy>
```

This will exclude all the wsdl folders you have in your layout folder.